# Am I using local variables in a defined manner?

Tags: c

I'm not sure if the way I am creating my local variables is undefined behavior.

Both N and L hold a pointer to a temporary stack address. Is this safe? Will the compiler forget I'm using a pointer to a stack address and overwrite it with something else, such as other local variables? I know once the scope of the function ends it is unsafe. But I am unsure about the examples below. Any insight will be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

```
struct Node { /* ... */ };

struct Node*
Node_setNode(struct Node* node)
{
    /* ... */
    return node;
}

struct List { /* ... */ };

void
List_push(struct List* list, struct Node* node)
{
    /* ... */
    list->next = node;
}


int main()
{

    struct Node* N = Node_setNode((& ((struct Node){ 0 })));
    struct List L;
    List_push(&L, (& ((struct Node){ 0 })));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure taking a pointer to `(struct Node){0}` like that isn't safe. I'm not sure why it compiles at all, though, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @user2357112 The effect of `(struct Node){ 0 }` is like declaring `struct Node tmp = {0};` but without naming a local variable.  It will create a space on the stack.  I find it hard to read, so I wouldn't recommend it, but it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of a stack is that you can push things on top of it.

When you call another function, you push a new stack frame with its local variables, without affecting the lower stack frame from `main()`.

Variables declared in a function will stay in its stack until it returns.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm trying to understand if using pointers to stack addresses in the way I show will not be overwritten by other local variables in the same stack frame.

Comment: @joe.ds: The compiler will not overwrite addresses for variables that are still in scope.

Answer (score 2):

No, the compiler will not forget about your local variables.  The way you're using them is safe and good.

Just make sure you never return a pointer to something on the stack and you should be fine.